# The value from a function returns undefined when passed through another function

Tags: javascript, html, function, scope

I am currently building a quiz app that automatically prints out a random arithmetic quiz with a countdown timer. I must say I am scared of being blocked for asking this question but I decided to take the risk.

This is the block of code that prints out a question from the array of questions:

```
function generateQuestion() {
  question.textContent = quizzes[Math.trunc(Math.random() * quizzes.length)];
  const questionNumber = question.textContent;
  return questionNumber;
}
```

This is the code block that evaluates the arithmetic problem in the array, solves and returns feedback:

```
const correctAnswer = eval(generateQuestion());  // A stand-alone code not inside any function. Reason explained below

function checkAnswer() {
  console.log(correctAnswer);
  if (correctAnswer === Number(answer.value)) {
    feedback.textContent = "Correct!";
    score++;
    document.querySelector(".score").textContent = score;
    answer.value = "";
  } else {
    feedback.textContent = "Wrong!";
  }
}
```

At first, it scores you correctly when you input the correct answer but subsequent questions are marked wrong.

I tried debugging by printing values to the console then I found out this block of code: const `correctAnswer = eval(generateQuestion());` was still holding the previous value. I could not place it into the `function checkAnswer()`  as this continued to return undefined.

Is there a way to go around this or am I missing something?

Comment: You're only setting `correctAnswer` when the page loads. You need to update it when you go to a new question.

Comment: Which means it shouldn't be declared `const`. It should be an ordinary variable that you can reassign.

Comment: Thanks immensely champ @Barmar . Can't thank you enough. Mind making it an answer so I could upvote it? Just my little way of appreciation

Comment: I don't know how to write this as an answer, because I don't know where the code should be moved to. There's not enough code here to tell where it belongs.

Comment: Oh, I get it. Just didn't want to scare anyone with too much code. Thanks again.